# Show that if x divides a power of 2, then x is a power of 2

Tags: proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that if $x$ divides $2^a$ for some integer $a \geq 0$, then $x = 2^b$, where $a \geq b$. In other words, if $x$ divides a power of 2, then $x$ is a power of 2. This makes sense, since the all the factors of a power of 2 are also powers of 2, e.g. the factors of 256 are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256. But I'm not so sure how to word this in a rigorous fashion.

A related question: Does this extend to powers of any integer, instead of just 2? If $x$ divides $k^a$, does $x = k^b$?

Comment: You need this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: For the related question: what happens if $k=4$? or $k=15$?

Comment: For related question it extends to powers of some integers can you guess which ones? 7 is one of them.

Comment: Ah, a counterexample. That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the related question, no.  Let $k=4$ and $x=8$.  $8$ divides $4^2$, but $8$ is no  integer power of 4.

This does extend to any prime $k$, however.

Comment: Superb, thanks. This is what I'm thinking: assume the contrary, so x divides 2^a but x is not a power of 2. Thus, x contains a prime factor greater than 2. Since 2^a has no prime factors greater than 2, x does not divide 2^a, which is a contradiction. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I suppose I could also generalize this to any prime p: assume the contrary, so x divides p^a but x is not a power of p. Thus, x contains some prime factor q such that p =\= q. Since p^a has no prime factors q, x does not divide p^a, which is a contradiction.